# Kali on RPI, can't upgrade Kernel and install current headers, or find old headers to build

Tags: linux, drivers, compiling, kali-linux, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi 2B and installed Kali Linux 2016.2 with kernel 4.1.19-v7 that I downloaded from the Kali website. It is working well, but for some utilities to work, I need to update my wireless drivers for the DREADED EDIMAX EW-7811. I want to compile them from source provided by Edimax, so I need to set up a build environment.

I have done this twice on Ubuntu and Raspbian by installing linux-headers and build-essentials and then make...etc. When I look for linux-headers in apt, I can find recent headers for 4.8.*, but not 4.1.19 that came with the image.

So now I see 2 options, upgrade Kali to 4.8 or search out headers for this old version.

- I tried to do a dist-upgrade and reboot. Still at 4.1.19-v7 (cname -r).
- I installed linux-image-4.8.0-kali1-armmp. This installed without error, my /boot folder has some new options, but after a reboot, uname -r still gives me 4.1.19-v7.

I wasn't trying to build a new kernel, just update from the repos. Since a RPi image doesn't use grub, how in the world do I tell the pi to boot the NEW kernel that it just installed?

What is the kali/pi way of doing do-dist-upgrade? Is it not upgrading because it knows that it won't work? If I succeed, will I have broken something? If I can't do that, how do I find the old headers so that I can build and move on? Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: I just ran into this same issue on a pi 3 rev-b. I have the newest available image and header files installed but no way to boot to them. No more grub. I tried Synaptic but that only showed the new headers I installed. If anyone has figured this out yet, please do post. I've been searching for about a week. This poor guy has been hanging for 9 months. I did do the dist-upgrade, updates etc. And BTW, THANK YOU so much to this community! This is my first post simply because over the last 10 years or so, I've found the answer to every question I had here! Your snippets have been simply amazing!